# can anyone tell me what mgetline is doing in ? i cant understand

Tags: c, algorithm

i could not understand what mgetline does in this code.
anyone can help me?

```
int mgetline(char s[],int lim)
{
    int c, i;
    
    for(i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    
    if(c == '\n')
    {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    
    s[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}
```

Comment: It does what gets does with the added benefit that you are able to specify the number of characters to read so you don't overflow the input buffer.  Additionally, it ensures that the string is null-terminated.  Is there some line that is giving you trouble understanding?

Comment: As you can see from the `getchar()` call, the function reads some input. For your progress in learning C it would be better to analyze the code yourself as far as possible and ask specific questions. You can also run your program in a debugger step-by-step to see how it works. Unfortunately the `for` loop might be difficult to debug because multiple conditions are combined inside the `for` statement.

Comment: It loads the passed array with a line of text.  What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: Note, there's a potential buffer overrun when `lim` is 1. `c` should be initialized to anything that's not `\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function basically reads characters one-by-one from the the standard input stream `stdin` until you enter a `\n` (newline) or the array limit of `s`, `lim`, is reached. The characters are stored in the `char s[]` and the length of what was read is returned.

It's hard to answer with more detail since it's a little unclear what it is you don't understand, but I've tried to annotate the code to make it somewhat clearer.

This is the same code, only reformatted to fit my comments.

```
int mgetline(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i;
    
    for(i = 0;                // init-statement, start with `i` at zero
        i < lim - 1           // condition, `i` must be less than `lim - 1`
        &&                    // condition, logical AND
        (c = getchar()) !=EOF // (function call, assignment) condition, `c` must not be EOF
        &&                    // condition, logical AND
        c != '\n';            // condition, `c` must not be `\n` (newline)
        ++i)                  // iteration_expression, increase i by one
    {
        s[i] = c;             // store the value of `c` in `s[i]`
    }

    if(c == '\n') {           // if a newline was the last character read
        s[i] = c;             // store it
        ++i;                  // and increase i by one
    }
    
    s[i] = '\0';              // store a null terminator last

    return i;                 // return the length of the string stored in `s`
}
```

In the `condition` part of the `for` loop you have 3 conditions that must all be `true` for the loop to enter the statement `for(...;...;...)` *`statement`*. I've made that statement into a code block to make it easier to see the scope. `EOF` is a special value that is returned by `getchar()` if the input stream (`stdin`) is closed.

Note: If you pass an array of *one* `char` (`lim == 1`) this function will cause *undefined behavior*. Any program reading uninitialized variables has *undefined behavior* - and that's a bad thing. In this case, if `lim == 1`, you will read `c` after the loop and `c` will then still be uninitialized.

Either initialize it:

```
int mgetline(char s[], int lim) {
    int c = 0, i;
```

or bail out of the function:

```
int mgetline(char s[], int lim) {
    if(lim < 2) {
        if(lim == 1) s[0] = '\0';
        return 0;
    }
    int c, i;
```

Comment: The reading of characters also stops if there's an end of file, or a read error.

Comment: @PaulHankin The `EOF` is out there to the right in the comment section. "_`c` must not be EOF_" - and I tried to explain what `EOF` is in the text below. Both a normal end-of-file and a read error will make it return `EOF` so it covers both cases.

Comment: About lim==1, if variable c is not initialized and if it happens by chance to be equal to \n, then TWO bytes are written to buffer s[].

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica They may be - if `lim == 1` the program has undefined behavior and what happens then is ... undefined.